# How to receive all friends scores from app using an open graph API?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm following the Facebook tutorial on how to implement Facebook into a game app for Android. I'm on the "High Scoreboard" [part towards the end of step 1.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/open-graph/) In this step they provide a way of retrieving friends high scores but they use a specific domain name to their app's server space: `"http://www.friendsmash.com/scores".` I was wondering if its possible to just retrieve friends high scores from Facebook and if so how? Any help, suggestions, or advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks!